# Django template - Calculate the number of months between today and a variable date

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a variable that is a date and I want to calculate the months' difference between it and today. The first try was to calculate this in the view but I prefer to do this calculation on the UI when it is needed. I have tried declaring and subtracting the values in the sample code here but I ran into syntax errors though in python this works well.

This is what I tried in the templates

```
{% with duration=(organisation.date_founded.year - today.year) * 12 + (date_started.month - today.month) %}
  { duration }}
% endwith %}
```

This is the python version of it

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
num_months = (date_started.year - today.year) * 12 + (date_started.month - today.month)
```

Comment: You can create a [Custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) for calculating the no. of months & use it in your template.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have methods on your model that will be accessible when needed in the template. I'm not sure about your calculations, but for example:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    date_founded = models.DateTimeField()

    def time_since_founded(self):
        return datetime.now() - self.date_founded # and so on..
```

In the template, depending on the name you gave in the context:

```
{{ organisation.time_since_founded }}
```

There is also a built-in template filter called `timesince`:

```
{{ organisation|timesince:date_founded }}
```